# Reading a Google Spreadsheet into Ruby Objects (or settle for a file download)

Tags: ruby, google-api-ruby-client

I think it's probably simplest to start with my use case:

I'm trying to read the contents of a Google Spreadsheet into ruby, and then use that data for other purposes. This needs to happen server-to-server.

Here's what I've tried:

1. First I tried to use this [google drive gem](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby). Since my interaction needs to be server to server (i.e. a service account), I couldn't get this to work (someone please let me know if they've managed this!)
2. Next, I tried using the [latest google-api-ruby gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client), and, following its documentation, was successfully able to authenticate my service account, and have been able to get lists of files, etc. So basically the API is authenticated and working.

The latest issue is that Google Spreadsheets can't be downloaded using the normal `download_dest` parameter on the `get_file` method (sorry - would post links to relevant documentation here, but don't have enough rep to do so). So I'm not really sure how to proceed with downloading the relevant file (I understand how to get an export_link), but have no clue how to then prepare the next request).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's some basic code for reference -

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
ENV["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'path/to/my/creds.json'
auth = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)

drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = auth

ss = drive.get_file('my_spreadsheet_id')
export_url = ss.export_links
# what now?
```